# Gmailapp trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to continuously monitor a gmail inbox with an apps script.  I want to use the email subject line as an input.

Is there a way to set up a trigger or filter so that every email received triggers a script to run?  Ideally there is some kind of *onReceive* class.

Only other option I can think of is set up a **cron** to keep running the script.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is an onReceive trigger. A cron is your best bet. Depending on what you're doing, running every minute would not be that bad.

Comment: THanks Phil.  1 minute is not so bad for my application.

Comment: To make it quicker, you could set up a filter that applies a label to *all* incoming emails. Let's call it "scriptunread". Then when your script runs, it retrieves all messages with label "scriptunread" then you do whatever you have to with them, and then you remove the label "scriptunread".

Comment: Yes, that works well (I now have multiple scripts doing this).